# Does Microsoft Graph have lastModifiedDateTime to detect latest entity changes?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Some of the Graph API return a lot of data and require paging. Exists a lastModifiedDateTime property to get only changed rows, such as to make this call that returns users who are modified since a given date?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt '2020-01-01T12:00:00Z'
```

or get the classes that have changed (Educational API)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt '2020-01-01T12:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Property you are trying i.e., 'lastModifiedDateTime'  is not part of the MS Graph.

In Ms Graph this is possible with [directoryAudits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method which contains all information related to changes(logs) in Azure AD.

To Get the last activity in azure you need to use `'activityDateTime'` property and to get the user information `'initiatedBy'` property.

Comment: This sounds like too much work for something simple and so common. Also, some entities, such as Assignments (EDU Teams) have lastModifiedDateTime. What is stopping us from propagating this to all entities?

Comment: Hi @Ted, This is by design and the only approach.